# Combine edges when node degree is n in networkx

Tags: python, graph, networkx, topology

I have an undirected graph as follows:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

l = [('1','2'),('2','3'),('3','4'),('3','5'),('1','6'),('6','7'),('6','8'),('9','8')]

G=nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(l)
nx.draw_networkx(G,with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

I want to combine edges when node satisfies `degree=n(like 2)`. I need remove node `1`,`2` and `8`,and connect `3-6` and `6-9` in my example. So I expect the results to be as follows.
[image]

How can I do it? Thanks in advaence

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

l = [('1','2'),('2','3'),('3','4'),('3','5'),('1','6'),('6','7'),('6','8'),('9','8')]

G=nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(l)

# Select all nodes with only 2 neighbors
nodes_to_remove = [n for n in G.nodes if len(list(G.neighbors(n))) == 2]

# For each of those nodes
for node in nodes_to_remove:
    # We add an edge between neighbors (len == 2 so it is correct)
    G.add_edge(*G.neighbors(node))
    # And delete the node
    G.remove_node(node)

nx.draw(G,with_labels=True)
```

[image]

Comment: It shows `TypeError: add_edge() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given` when `n=3`

Comment: `*G.neighbors(node)` works only if number of neighbors equal to 2. If you want to remove nodes with more neighbors, you should select them manually.

Comment: But my mistake happened in the `G.add_edge(*G.neighbors(node))` line when I set `nodes_to_remove = [n for n in G.nodes if len(list(G.neighbors(n))) == 3]`. Hou can I select them manually? Please forgive me for being a new to networkx.

Comment: Instead of `*G.neighbors(node)` you should write something like `list(G.neighbors(node))[0], list(G.neighbors(node))[1]`. But be careful! If you want to create several edges, you should check what exactly you are creating!

Comment: What do you mean with two loop instead of it? Please give the code.

Comment: Not two loops, but one tuple in that you should choose two nodes from 3/4/5 or more.